# Negative lookahead in R not behaving as expected

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to replace instances in a string which begin with `abc` in a text I'm working with in R. The output text is highlighted in HTML over a couple of passes, so I need the replacement to ignore text inside HTML carets.

The following seems to work in Python but I'm not getting any hits on my regex in R. All help appreciated.

```
test <- 'abcdef abc<span abc>defabc abcdef</span> abc defabc'
gsub('\\babc\\(?![^<]*>\\)', 'xxx', test)
```

Expected output:

```
xxxdef xxx<span abc>defabc xxxdef</span> xxx defabc
```

Instead it is ignoring all instances of `abc`.

Comment: keep in mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove unnecessary escapes and use `perl=TRUE`:

```
test <- 'abcdef abc<span abc>defabc abcdef</span> abc defabc'
gsub('\\babc(?![^<]*>)', 'xxx', test, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "xxxdef xxx<span abc>defabc xxxdef</span> xxx defabc"
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/qI9jWB)

When you escape `(`, it matches a literal `(` symbol, so, in your pattern, `\\(?![^<]*>\\)` matches a `(` 1 or 0 times, then `!`, then 0+ chars other than `<`, then `>` and a literal `)`. In my regex, `(?![^<]*>)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if an `abc` is followed with any 0+ chars other than `<` and then a `>`.

Without `perl=TRUE`, R `gsub` uses the TRE regex flavor that does not support lookarounds (even lookaheads). Thus, you have to tell `gsub` via `perl=TRUE` that you want the PCRE engine to be used.

See the [online PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF0hON/1).

Comment: > You need to remove unnecessary escapes

!@#$@#!%%

Thanks Wiktor!

Comment: `perl=TRUE` is something I always forget. Thanks.

Comment: @LazarusThurston Sometimes, you do not need that, you'd choose not to use `perl=TRUE` very seldom, in most cases, yes, `perl=TRUE` is a good idea. See the [TRE  vs. PCRE differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251004/3832970).